# Redirect URLs with a trailing slash to URLs with no trailing slash via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Can someone please help me to clean this up? I have let a developer add these previous rules. I'm not entirely sure what these are for, but what I wanted to add was the last rule that will redirect all trailing slash at the end URL's to non-trailing slash. But when I saved the file, nothing happened on the frontend? If someone could explain to me what these rules are for and what could be deleted, that would be great!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^nl/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

UPDATE

So I have changed the order, the redirect works on the website, but the /wp-admin page is now in a redirect loop. Does anyone know what to do?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^nl/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, keep it up. Please do mention what sample URL you are hitting and what error you are getting eg: 404, 500 etc That will help us to understand your issue more.

Comment: You need to do things like this in the correct order. These RewriteConds check if what was requested does not match onto an existing file or folder, and if that is not the case, the request gets rewritten to the index.php. So if you are trying to remove the trailing slash from URL that do not directly map onto the file system, you would need to do it before that.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! You could have a look at https://aduh.shop/sweaters/ or https://aduh.shop/sweaters. Both versions still exist now.

Comment: @CBroe So where do I need to check first if i'm using Wordpress? And could you tell me what the correct order is?

Comment: _"And could you tell me what the correct order is?"_ - hm, I thought I more or less just did, with the explanation I gave you.

Comment: _"So where do I need to check first if i'm using Wordpress?"_ - you don't need to check that ... rewrites to `/wp-login.php` would be a weird coincidence if this was _not_ a WordPress, but the issue is actually independent of whether it is or not.

Comment: So I have changed the order, but now the /admin page is in a redirect loop. Why is that happening?